# How to make ISO file "bootable" on USB

Tags: usb, iso

I have downloaded the Ubuntu (desktop) ISO file and copied it to a USB drive. When I try to boot from it, I get a disk error. When I try to open the file within Windows, it launches my CD Burning program.

I have a 386 machine (IBM Thinkpad) running XP.

Comment: use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to bootable your USB flash drive

Comment: See the [help page in Ubuntu web site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for how to create a Live USB from the ISO file. Just copying the file into an USB drive won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pendrive installer, available at http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/.  The information on how to do this is located on Ubuntu.com at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows